# Show and hide an element based on a service value

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to migrate to the Angular 2 way of doing things and removing logic from existing controllers is my first goal. One issue I'm facing is how to toggle the visibility of an element based on a value in a service/factory.

Previously I would have;

1) injected the service into the controller

```
.controller(MyController, function(MyService))
```

2) exposed it as a variable (using controllerAs syntax)

```
this.showWhen = MyService.serverHasProcessed;
```

3) used an ng-show / ng-hide directive

```
<div ng-show="myCtrl.showWhen">...
```

As controllers will be dead in Angular 2 my first path in migrating was to create my own directive. I injected the service in there and went to use $element.hide() / $element.show() but these methods aren't available on angular element.

Should I just continue this way and copy the ng-show directive code of;

```
$animate[toBoolean(value) ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass'](element, 'ng-hide');
```

or is there a better way?

Comment: What was the problem with the "Previously I would have" approach? You haven't told us.

Comment: I've changed it a little to clarify. The "Previously I would have" litters your controllers with logic and as the 2.0 version will be removing controllers I'm trying to change the way I develop Angular. I just want to verify that I'm going down the right path before I continue further.

Comment: Use the angular 1 way. Angular 2 has changed drastically.

Answer (score 0):

Creating your own directive is a good step towards making things the angular way. Angular 2.0 will be killing controllers, but more in the sense of killing `ng-controller`.

Angular 2 will have classes as part of the component model, and controllers in Angular 1 can be classes, because internally the controller function is instantiated using the `new` keyword.

So a component model in Angular 2, is somewhat comparable to a directive controller in Angular 1.

Angular 1 (ES6)

```
function helloAppDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<span>{{helloApp.greeting}}</span>',
    controller: HelloAppController,
    controllerAs: 'helloApp'
  }
}

angular.module('helloModule', [])
       .directive('helloApp', helloAppDirective);

class HelloAppController {
  greeting: string;
  constructor() {
    this.greeting = 'hello';
  }
}
```

Angular 2

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello-app',
  template: new TemplateConfig({
    inline: '<span>{{greeting}}</span>',
    directives: []
  })
})
class HelloRootCmp {
  greeting:string;
  constructor() {
    this.greeting = 'hello';
  }
}
```

Basically the DDO is moving to an @attribute.